# Keep a server alive for each file in a directory

Tags: linux, deployment, automation

### Current situation

I am running a linux server (Arch). I have a server application which is executed like this:

```
run_server filename --port=xxxx
```

I have written systemd service files. Each one keeps a processes alive for a specific file on a specific port. When I want to serve up a new file, I copy the systemd service file; edit it; give it a new port; and enable/start the new service.

This is a lot of manual work, because the files are often added and removed by a team of people.

### Request

If I have a directory of files

```
directory/firstfile
directory/secondfile
....
```

I want to keep alive a single process for each file:

```
run_server firstfile --port=9001
run_server secondfile --port=9002
...
```

When a file is removed from the directory, the process should stop. When a file is added to the directory, a new process should be started.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can do that with a single perl or shell script, by looping into the directory (directory/file watcher) and executing commands depending on the result

Comment: For the first part: use template unit files. See "Creating Instance Units from Template Unit Files"  in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files  for example so that you have only one file for all the cases:

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Template Unit Files! Fantastic, I didn't know that was possible. Great tip.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've gone with a combo of the two commenters' advice.

1. Created a systemd templated unit file (`/etc/systemd/system/run_server@.service`)

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/../run_server %i
   ...
   ```
2. Create a systemd path service (`/etc/systemd/system/sync_server_units.path`) which monitors the directory

   ```
   [Path]
   PathModified=/path/to/directory
   ...
   ```
3. That kicks off (`/etc/systemd/system/sync_server_units.service`), which is a simple run_once:

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/../sync_server_units
   ```
4. Finally I have a script (`sync_server_units`) that compares the contents of the directory with the output of `systemctl list-units --all 'run_server@*'`, and enables/starts/stops/disables the templated service as needed.

Works well so far!